# User vs. System events in Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been reading the Google Maps API docs to see if it's possible to tell the difference between a system event vs. a user one?

For example, the `zoom_changed` event gets triggered when you use methods like `setZoom`, `fitBounds`, etc, which in my implementation is unsavoury, as I just want to know when the user actually changes the zoom level.

Unfortunately, the `click` event is only fired on the map itself, not the controls, so you can't rely on that method to help detect the users input.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I haven't been able to solve this using the Google Maps API, I have created a workaround which involves me calling this method before I change the map zoom or positioning without user interaction:

```
MapGraph.prototype.systemMove = function() {
  var _this = this;
  this.isMoving = true;
  return setTimeout(function() {
    return _this.isMoving = false;
  }, 500);
};
```

And my event bindings look like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'dragend', function(event) {
  if (!_this.isMoving) return _this.mapChanged();
});
```

Not perfect, but it does work.

Would love to see any other implementations though.

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider an alternate solution I proposed in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62716217/8245557), which does not rely on mouse events to recognize user-initiated changes.

Instead of trying to recognize user events, add a flag to the map whenever a programmatic change is initiated with `setZoom` or `fitBounds`.

```js
map.systemChange = true
map.setZoom()
```

Then check for (and reset) the flag in the event listener.

```js
map.addListener('zoom_changed', function () {
  if (map.systemChange) {
    map.systemChange = false  // Reset the flag for a system-initiated event
  } else {
    // Handle the user-initiated event
  }
});
```