# How to know if the user change zoom (Google Maps V3)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm developing an app with Google Maps and Angularjs. I have this code to control whether the zoom is changed

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function(){

  });
```

The question is, I need to execute this event only when the user changes the zoom. I have in my code a `fitBounds()` that change the zoom as well.

```
var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < latlng.length; i++) {
    latlngbounds.extend(latlng[i]);
  }

  map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
```

Is there an option to distinguish between user action and not?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I found the way

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'mousemove', function(){

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function(){

    });

  });
```

First, it detects if the mouse moves and then if the zoom if changed and works properly!

Comment: This should not be the accepted solution, it is not a currect solution to your problem. Also, it has unexpected side effects.

Answer (score 1):

The current accepted solution may not properly solve this question in a general case. Go to the [interactive demo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events) for map UI events in the Google Maps API docs. Note that if you position your cursor on the map and scroll with your mouse's scroll wheel, none of the `mouse` or `drag` events are fired because the mouse remains stationary.

The current solution assumes that no programmatic map updates will occur after the `mouseover` event, which may be true for the original poster's application but might not be true in a more general application.

I propose the alternate solution below.

First, wherever you programmatically update the map in your code, set a custom property on the map—we'll call ours `systemZoomChange`—that indicates the change was initiated programmatically.

```js
var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for (var i = 0; i < latlng.length; i++) {
  latlngbounds.extend(latlng[i]);
}

map.systemZoomChange = true
map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
```

Then on any event listeners, add a check for the custom `systemZoomChange` property, and reset it if flagged, to avoid acting on system events.

```js
map.addListener('zoom_changed', function () {
  if (map.systemZoomChange) {
    map.systemZoomChange = false  // Reset the flag for a system-initiated event
  } else {
    // Handle the user-initiated event
  }
});
```

Comment: Good solution, except you should set `map.systemZoomChange = true` **before** calling `fitBounds()` or `setZoom()`.

Comment: @MrUpsidown - Ah, silly mistake. I edited my answer. Thanks!